# ExtJS, how to bind ViewModel to component config parameters?

Tags: javascript, extjs, viewmodel

On ExtJS 6.02 I would like to bind a ViewModel to my component config parameters.

I tried what it says here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27284556 but it doesn't work, it's not binding.

This prints `Null` instead of `123`:

```js
Ext.define('MyApp.viewmodel.Test', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewModel',
    alias: 'viewmodel.test',
    data: {
        serverPathData: ''
    }
});

Ext.define('MyApp.view.TestFileField', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.field.Text',
    xtype: 'TestFileField',

    viewModel: {
        type: 'test'
    },
    config: {
        serverPath: null
    },
    publishes: 'serverPath',
    bind: {
        serverPath: '{serverPathData}'
    }
    , initComponent: function() {
        this.getViewModel().set('serverPathData', '123');
        this.getViewModel().notify();
        console.log(this.getServerPath());
        
        this.callParent()
    }
});

Ext.application({
    name: 'MyApp',
    launch: function() {
        var testFileField = Ext.widget({
            xtype: 'TestFileField',
            renderTo: Ext.getBody()
        });
    }
});
```

Using `testFileField.getViewModel().notify();` does solve the problem in this example, but in my case it doesn't.

I have a shared viewModel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found one solution, if I call `this.initBindable();` on initComponent it works:

```js
Ext.define('MyApp.viewmodel.Test', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewModel',
    alias: 'viewmodel.test',
    data: {
        serverPathData: ''
    }
});

Ext.define('MyApp.view.TestFileField', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.field.Text',
    xtype: 'TestFileField',

    viewModel: {
        type: 'test'
    },
    config: {
        serverPath: null
    },
    publishes: 'serverPath',
    bind: {
        serverPath: '{serverPathData}'
    }
    , initComponent: function() {
        this.initBindable();
        this.getViewModel().set('serverPathData', '123');
        this.getViewModel().notify();
        console.log(this.getServerPath());
        console.log(this.getViewModel().data);
        this.callParent();
    }
});

Ext.application({
    name: 'MyApp',
    launch: function() {
        var testFileField = Ext.widget({
            xtype: 'TestFileField',
            renderTo: Ext.getBody()
        });
    }
});
```

The problem with this is that this method is private and is already called on `beforeRender` and `afterRender` and I don't know if calling it on `initComponent` or `constructor` could cause some problem.